# Is it possible to make a living selling exploits?

Tags: exploit, career, software

Is it possible to make a living (say $75k+ a year) finding and selling vulnerabilities? It doesn't matter (for the sake of this question) whether it means selling purely to a bug bounty program or through a broker.

Thank you.

Comment: While many security-defeating questions on here are for the purposes of learning how to guard a system, I'm not sure if I see the goodness of this question...what beneficial purpose is this serving?

Comment: Answers would be opinion-based as it's not a ***legal job***.

Comment: @e-sushi That’s actually an interesting question: isn’t it legal? Are you sure? If so, *why* isn’t it legal? I agree that it’s deeply immoral. But I’m having a hard time to see where it contravenes the law.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, just ask an average arms dealer how his/her job worked out in the end.

Comment: @e-sushi Not sure I get this: arms sale is a legal, blooming, billions-dollar business. So I’m guessing it worked out incredibly well for them. And unlike sale of exploits it is heavily regulated: I could, without much effort, point you to the relevant laws regulating arms sale. I know of no such laws concerning the sale of exploits.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are ignoring the fact that there very well are (hidden) regulations in place. Let’t take a fictive example: we two group up to found a company to sell exploits we find. One day, we sell an exploit to a client which happens to be a terrorist, foreign-government agent, or whatever. When that exploit is used to target the country we live in, **nothing** will save us. We’ld have supplied ”an enemy of the state” with ”a weapon”. There are ample laws which would break our necks in that case – as we would have engaged in illegal, criminal activity by providing an electronic weapon.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Differently stated: I’ld rather go for the regulated gun-and-bullets market than for exploits… the later doesn’t offer you ***any regulated protection***. Instead, there are ***many regulations and laws*** prohibiting things which would practically boil down to electronic warfare. Don’t get me wrong, some companies (I’m looking towards the French riviera) make a living from exploits… but I can assure you they’re walking a thin line and they’re far from safe when sh#t hits the fan. All that’s left: you could try to sell exploits to your own government. (Good luck with that one…)

Comment: @e-sushi “We’ld have supplied ‘an enemy of the state’ with ‘a weapon’.” — Is that a fact? I’m not aware of any such law. At any rate, this is *precisely* what I’m questioning here. I agree that it’s *potentially* a legal minefield.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To avoid extended discussions in the comment area, let me just say *I ain't stopping anyone.* ;) In case you want to talk more, drop an email (See my profile)

Answer (score 4):

Is it **possible**? Of course it's *possible*. It's also quite possible for you to make a living by regularly discovering new and novel cures to common diseases.

On the other hand, if you're asking whether or not it's **likely** that **you** will make a living by discovering exploits one after another, let's start with this: How many have you discovered so far? How much have you made in bounties off the bugs you've discovered? How much time and research has it taken you to discover each one? Judging by your current discovery rate and your income so far, how much do you expect to make by devoting your efforts full-time to this endeavor? If the answer to that question is $0, then I would recommend an alternate career path.

Answer (score 2):

Only you can answer that question.  What is your track record at analyzing software for flaws?  How many do you find a week?  Compare that to the payouts that you've seen, such as pwn2own, or Microsoft's bug bounty programs?  Bottom line: if you aren't already doing it, that's your answer.

Another thing to consider is the risk:  companies are under no obligation to continue to pay for bugs, so it's never going to be a guaranteed income.  And once Chip and PIN fully rolls out across the globe it might make stealing credit card numbers worthless, meaning fewer criminals with less need for 0days, meaning the prices would go down.

And there's also the ethics of selling 0days to the black market - you would be placing yourself at risk of arrest.  It doesn't matter if you think it's legal, if a random armchair lawyer on stackexchange thinks it's legal, or if the EFF thinks it's legal.  Some politician might simply decide to make it illegal.  Some cybercop might re-interpret the laws to fit their situation and drag you into court anyway.  Or some other country might think it's illegal and request your extradition.